# Send two argument in an onchange function call contained in a PHP echo statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to send two arguments (a PHP variable $sub_id and an input event) in an onchange function call, but this call (and the JS) is contained in a PHP echo statement. I am struggling with the quotations. A simplified example:

```
echo"
<form>
  ...
  <input type='file' onchange='loadImagePreview($sub_id, event)'>
  ...
</form>

...

<script>
   function loadImagePreview(submissionId, event) {
     ...
   }

</script>
";
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is `$sub_id`? Is it a string that you want to pass into your Javascript as a string literal? If so, you need to make sure you output literal quotes on either side of the value, which you aren't here. Of course that's hard to do when `echo`ing a long string like this, which is not a good way to output long stretches of HTML anyway. Just put this outside PHP tags, so it's rendered as HTML, and insert the value like this: `onchange='loadImagePreview("<?php echo $sub_id; ?>", event)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing was the escaped double quotes around `$sub_id`, unless it is an integer, then it is not necessary. Like this:

```
echo"
<form>
  ...
  <input type='file' onchange='loadImagePreview(\"$sub_id\", event)'>
  ...
</form>

...

<script>
   function loadImagePreview(submissionId, event) {
     ...
   }

</script>
";
```

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed an integer! So my simplified example was correct. I actually did not test it before I posted the question (apologies). Nonetheless, I need to refresh my concatenation theory.